# React Router wildcard paths on root directory

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Is it possible, like most of the social media websites to do something like

somesite.com/username but still have certain paths like /login or /settings

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route path="/:id - but not /login or /settings" component={User} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

with the suggestions of using exact

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Route path="/:id" component={User} />
        <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />           

    </div>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')

const User = () => {    
    return (
        <h1>user</h1>
    )
}

const Settings = () => {    
    return (
        <h1>settings</h1>
    )
}
```

going to /settings would display

user

settings

Comment: explain more what you r asking

Comment: I want to use the router in a way I can access users' profiles with somesite.com/sangram or somesite.com/totalnoob while also allowing users to use /settings or /login for other components

Answer (score 7):

Yes, just move the paths without variables above the paths with a variable:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
  <Route path="/:id" component={User} />
</Switch>
```

You need to to this because React Router will match the routes from the first one to the last one - if you put the one with `:id` first, it will always get matched.

The purpose of the Switch component here is to ensure only the *first* matching route renders its component.

Comment: the contents of the User component shows up on the /login and /settings routes when I try that

Comment: I've just updated the answer - as Jan mentioned, you might need to set the `exact` prop... Or use a `Switch`.

Comment: The `exact` prop won't do the trick here because pretty much any string without `/` will "exact"ly match the pattern `"/:id"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using the `exact` attribute:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route path="/:id" component={User} />
            <Route path="/login" exact={true} component={Login} />
            <Route path="/settings" exact={true} component={Settings} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

See documentation: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#exact-bool

Comment: with this, going to /settings would show the contents of the User component. I've updated the question with the code

Comment: Use a `<Switch>` around https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md

Comment: Switch is perfect. Thanks